# Border between monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, external-monitor

In a dual-monitor setup, moving a window on the left screen to the right side will have a (small) "block" when the window aligns with the left screen's right border. This is useful to position a window at the right-hand side of the left screen.

Now, my left monitor is my primary screen so I have the panels on the left-hand screen. Moving the mouse to the top-right corner where the user menu including logoff/shutdown is, is not so easy because unless I navigate very carefully I usually end up with my mouse on the right screen and have to backtrack.

Is there a feature (I am using gnome3, btw) that allows me to set up some kind of border between the two screens so that it will take just a little bit more effort to move the mouse from left to right screen?

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to switch to Unity, it has a new "sticky edges" feature that lets you have some resistance in between monitors so that the mouse doesn't just go across freely. It is in the `Displays` settings, as demonstrated here:

[image]

Comment: That's only for dragging windows on/between monitors. It doesn't answer OP at all.